# Ionic: Keyboard overlaps a focused text input on iOS 11

Tags: javascript, ios, css, ionic-framework

**Issue**

When I click the text input from the modal, a keyboard overlaps the text input. This issue has found during testing on iPhone SE (iOS 11) device.

I've looked up a several threads and tried to figure out on my own, but I've realized that my current problem has been a chronic issue for Ionic developers until now.

**These are the related links to my issue.** I've tried given solutions from links below, but none of them worked with my code.

- [Keyboard issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11501)
- [Keyboard overlaps the text input when the input is placed inside an ion-footer](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/7149)
- [Keyboard hides input until I start typing](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-hides-input-until-i-start-typing/60827/2)
- [Ionic 2 On-Screen Keyboard Covers Focused Input Element Inside Grid Component](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/10629)

**Version Info**

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
Node       : v8.9.0
npm        : 5.5.1
OS         : macOS High Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
```

**Expected behavior**

Ion input should stay in a position right above the keyboard while a user types some messages.

**Actual behavior**

[image]

**app.component.ts**

I've included `keyboard.disableScroll(true);` inside `platform.ready()` to prevent navbar crashing issue. Without this line of code, the keyboard works fine with the input text. But it pushes the whole content to the top including navbar, thus for the first few messages appear to be hidden.

Any ideas?

**UPDATED**

I'm not sure the way I've solved the issue is the best solution, but for now, I replaced the content and footer's margin-bottom with a sum of an initial height of text area and the keyboard height.

*If you have a better solution, feel free to leave it as an answer.*

Here's the final result.

[image]

Comment: do you have the latest cordova-plugin-keyboard installed?

Comment: I've checked my package.json file, and I'm using ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 at the moment.

Comment: I figured it out.

Comment: I have the same issue above, which ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1.Have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've just updated the post and posted the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was having similar problems in a similar project setup where the keyboard in iOS overlapped the footer bar in ionic.  I was able to solve it by removing the `ionic-plugin-keyboard@2.2.1` and adding `cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard@2.0.5` https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard

Apparently I didn't notice that `ionic-plugin-keyboard` was deprecated as I was upgrading my project from Ionic 1 to 2, I'm guessing you may have been in a similar position.

Comment: Did the newly added plugin solve the problem right away without using any dirty extra work?

Comment: Fixed my problems with the bottom bar being hidden in iOS.  Only thing I changed was the plugin.

Comment: I'll try and to see how it goes. Will accept your answer if everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

To make things happen, first, you need to get the height of three elements like the example code below. For example,

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;

ionViewDidLoad() {
  if (this.platform.is('ios'))
    this.addKeyboardListeners();

  this.scrollContentElement = this.content.getScrollElement();
  this.footerElement = document.getElementsByTagName('your page component')[0].getElementsByTagName('ion-footer')[0];
  this.inputElement = document.getElementsByTagName('your page component')[0].getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
}
```

Then, add a keyboard listener for ios platform.

```
addKeyboardListeners() {
  this.keyboardHideSub = this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(() => {
    let marginBottom = this.textareaHeight - this.initialTextAreaHeight + 44;
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.scrollContentElement, 'marginBottom', marginBottom + 'px');
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.footerElement, 'marginBottom', '0px')
  });

  this.keybaordShowSub = this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe((e) => {
    let newHeight = (e['keyboardHeight']) + this.textareaHeight - this.initialTextAreaHeight;
    let marginBottom = newHeight + 44 + 'px';
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.scrollContentElement, 'marginBottom', marginBottom);
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.footerElement, 'marginBottom', e['keyboardHeight'] + 'px');
    this.updateScroll(250);
  });
}
```

Lastly, it is important to unsubscribe the keyboard listeners whenever you leave the page.
Make it as a method and call it from wherever you need to.

```
removeKeyboardListeners() {
  this.keyboardHideSub.unsubscribe();
  this.keybaordShowSub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: I have this problem these days. I'm learning Ionic + Meteor following the guide: https://angular-meteor.com/tutorials/whatsapp2/ionic/setup.  In fact there is no problem with English keyboard, when switch to Chinese keyboard the input field is covered. I can't understand your method, I think it      's too complicate , there must be some simple way.

Comment: @sitexa I agree with you. This isn't the best solution. I can't believe the fact that the issue still has not been closed. I hope the Ionic team proposes some cleaner ways of implementing the current problem asap that Ionic developers are facing in.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of @coderroggie saved my life!

Just uninstall **ionic-plugin-keyboard** and then install c**ordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard** and it will work.

In my case I had two windows:
- Chat List with ion-footer with input: when the input has focus the keyboard pushed all content up (including navbar).

- Search with top searchbar and autocomplete List: when searchbar has focus the keyboard overlap the list.

Thank you @coderroggie.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that this is framework related issue. I was also facing the same in android. To fix this i have used keyboard plugin and it's functions to handle height of viewport. Below is the code-

```
constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private keyboard: Keyboard
  ) {
    if(this.platform.is('android')){
      this.keyboard.onKeyboardShow().subscribe((e) => {
        var keyboardHeight = e.keyboardHeight;
        if ($("html").hasClass("plt-android")) {
          keyboardHeight = keyboardHeight ? keyboardHeight : '337';
          ****337 is default height to handle if keyboard height not available****
              $('body').css('height', 'calc(100vh - ' + keyboardHeight + 'px)' );
            }
          });

          this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(e => {
            $('input, textarea').blur();
            if ($("html").hasClass("plt-android")) {
                $("body").css("height", "100vh");
            }
          });
    }
}
```

library--

```
npm install jquery
npm install @types/jquery
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard
npm install @ionic-native/keyboard
```

imports--

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import * as $ from "jquery";
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard/ngx';
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed

```
<ion-input type="tel" pattern="tel" autocomplete="tel (ionChange)="writeValue($event.target.value)"></ion-input>
```

to

```
<input type="tel" (change)="writeValue($event.target.value)" autocomplete="tel">
```

And added some styles

```
 input {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  input:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Finally, we got the perfect solution.

```
window.scrollBy(0, 100); // Scroll 100px downwards
window.scrollBy(100, 0); // Scroll 100px to the right
```

Comment: Where you added this